# Installing RubyMine on Windows 7 persistent error: "Could not find "README" in any of your source paths."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, rubymine

I installed ruby 1.9.3 w/ rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p194.exe, and then installed RubyMine right after, as per directions:

http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/quickstart/index.html

and

http://rubyinstaller.org/

I have git hub for windows already installed which I don't know if that could cause the problem.

I have also installed ruby and rails several times but I looked through the PATH environment variable for any no longer existing installations and removed them (after having already had this error) which didn't help.

Here are the settings I select in RubyMine.

[image: Settings]

The error message:

"C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\Ruby193\bin/rails *3.2.6* new "D:/Program Files (x86)/Git/Rails App/asfasf" --skip-test-unit --javascript=jquery --skip --database=postgresql
       exist  D:/Program Files (x86)/Git/Rails App/asfasf
Could not find "README" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates

Process finished with exit code 1"

[image: The Error]

I apologize if I come across as angry / frustrated (I edited this several times to remove it) as I have been trying to get RubyMine to work on Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04 and neither have been successful.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continued searching through the web for information and remembered somewhere installing rails on windows previously that for some reasons files couldn't have spaces in them.

Long story short: make sure your path doesn't have spaces in the name because it breaks rubymine or rails or something along the way.

Changing my project folder to a destination with no spaces solved the problem.